# PHP - URL displays fine in Chrome and IE8, but not in Firefox 3.0.11

Tags: php, url, cross-browser

My site prints out URLs in a table.  In Chrome and IE8, the URLs look great.  In Firefox 3.0.11, the URLs only display up until the second forward slash.

So for example, "nytimes.com/pages/world/americas/index.html" is just "nytimes.com/pages" in Firefox.

Any ideas why?  The code is below.

Edit:  I'm beginning to think this is a CSS issue because when I remove my styles, the link displays correctly in Firefox.  I'm going to re-post this as a CSS issue.

Thanks in advance,

John

```
print "<td class='sitename'>".'<a href="http://'.$row['site'].'" class="links2">'.$row['site'].'</a>'."</td>";
```

Edit: here is an HTML printout of a result:

```
<td class='sitename'><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miami" class="links2">en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miami</a></td>
```

In Firefox, it only displays "en.wikipedia.org/wiki"

Comment: Can you paste some of the HTML source from the page?

Comment: "nytimes.com/pages/world/americas/index.html" is no valid URI. your missing the protocol. try "http://nytimes.com/pages/world/americas/index.html" instead.

Comment: okay, the SO comment system just cut the "h t t p : / /"; away ...

Comment: But he has an h t t p : / / at the beginning of the a tag.

Comment: arg ... you're right ... sry! :/

Comment: @Mark Biek: I posted some more code above.  It shows how the user enters the URLs into the database.

Comment: What I'd really like to see is HTML from the rendered page.  That might give a clue as to what's going on.

Comment: <td class='sitename'><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miami" class="links2">en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miami</a></td>

Comment: For the HTML above, the page in Firefox only displays "en.wikipedia.org/wiki", not "en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miami".

Comment: And again, it displays "en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miami" in Chrome and IE8.

Comment: Does it have something to do with the way Firefox is reading my CSS?

Comment: In that case, Philippe is right.  You're missing the h t t p : / /.  Not sure why though.

Comment: THe HTML has a hred="h t t p : / /en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miami"... but the comment system removed the h t t p : / / when I typed it.

Comment: I'm not missing h t t p : / /

Comment: Could you put the HTML into your original post and format it with 4 spaces (like the other code blocks)?

Comment: There should be no reason this print statement produces any different HTML depending on your browser. I can only think that either your HTML is malformed in a way not evident here, or there's some CSS or Javascript issue particular to Firefox which is chopping a.link2 contents. As I doubt it's CSS, do you have any JavaScript for this page?

Comment: Yes, but the Javascript is not being applied to the table column in question.

Comment: Did you check to see if the URL text is simply wrapping?

Comment: How about a screenshot of the browser?

Answer (score 0):

If you actually see only a part of the link, it means that your variable is bogus. It might be coming from previously posted data.

Comment: But it looks fine in Chrome and IE8.  Plus, I tried it with newly posted data.

Comment: You seem to be forgetting that PHP is executed on the server, not on the browser. If you echo() it and it looks different in 2 browsers, the server must have received a different input from each, since the code that is executed does not change.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any pages that demo this problem you can link to? I think you're at a point where people need to see this happening to get more ideas about what it might be.

There should be no reason this print statement produces any different HTML depending on your browser. I can only think that either your HTML is malformed in a way not evident here, or there's some CSS or Javascript issue particular to Firefox which is chopping a.link2 contents. As I doubt it's CSS, and you say your JavaScript doesn't touch this column of the table, we'll need more details to answer this problem for you.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure, and because some **Firefox Add-ons** do unpredictable behavior. Run Firefox in the safe mode, and check it.